# FBSDKSharePhoto specify photo title or description

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

On Facebook's sharing documentation page, there's a screencap at the top which implies that you can share photos with a text from your app without using any sharing methods (like button, share button, etc).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#triggering

I tried to create the same within a test app but I am unable to find where should I assign the text to.

I have the following code which works fine, but doesn't contain any text.

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = self.postImage.image
photo.userGenerated = true

let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [ photo ]

FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: self)
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
content.contentTitle = "My awesome photo"
```

But this is not possible at the moment. Any other workaround to achieve this?

Comment: This is a known issue and will be addressed in an upcoming release of the SDK.

Comment: Ming Li - Was this ever fixed? I have a similar issue -- I can't add links to a photo using contentURL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802684/fbsdksharephoto-not-sharing-link-alongside-photo-using-swift

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
photo.caption = "My awesome photo"
```

Like this :

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = self.postImage.image
photo.userGenerated = true
//Your description here
photo.caption = "My awesome photo"
let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [ photo ]
FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: self)
```